# Can I decrease the width of microstrip at the pin?

Tags: pcb, rf, antenna, eaglecad, microstrip

I am trying to connect a 60 mil microstrip to the pin of IC. However, the width is relatively large to the space between pins on the IC. Can I decrease the width of microstrip where I connect it to the pin, so that it can be no clearance error?

In addition, when I route this microstrip to the pin, there will be a gray half circle like in the figure. Does any one know what it is? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a common problem, especially in routing of big BGA packages, where pad/ball pitch is rather small. As long as the narrower section is shorter than a quarter of shortest wavelength of your specific signal, this won't affect much your signal integrity (shape of waveform).

Regarding the grey semi-circle, you need to consult with user manual for the tool you are using.

Comment: isn't 60mil HUGE for a microstrip?

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami, regarding 60 mils - it would depend on desired characteristic impedance AND PCB stackup.

Comment: @ThePhoton w/h~2 for 50 ohms on FR4 ustrip, at least it was when I was doing it!

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help. For the 60 mil width, I am using 2 layer FR4 board. According to the manufacturer, I found the board thickness is 0.8mm, cooper thickness is 1oz (35um), and dielectric of FR4 is about 4.3. In order to get 50 Ohm impedance, I plug in my values into microstrip calculate online. From there, the result I got is 60 mil for 50 ohm impedance. Does the process sound reasonable? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami

Comment: @ThePhoton Mine W/h is about 2 for 2 FR4 layer board.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you! I am getting w/h ~2 in my result. If the trace thickness is 35um, I guess 60 mil is not too large in this case?

Comment: @LFJY, Trace thickness only causes a small adjustment to the Z0. The dielectric thickness (distance from trace to groundplane) is the "h" we're talking about here.